# To scan and list the wifi access points for SSID and RSSI

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android programming.

How can i use `WifiManager.startScan()` and `WifiManager.getScanResults()` to list all the wifi access points in the range of smartphone with their `SSID` and `RSSI` values. I need to repeat the scan once in every 30sec.

Can you please help me with a code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
    i.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(TAG, "opening wifimanager");
                WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                mWifiManager.getScanResults();

            }
        }
    ,i);



        mWifiManager.startScan();
```

And add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Link to wifi manager reference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html